Generalizing the property of linear independent set in infinite dimensional TVS
Given a infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$, and a countable set of vectors $\{v_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. I want to study the following property of $\{v_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$:
There exists sequences $\{\alpha_{i,j}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subset\mathbb{C}$ such that $\{\sum_{i=1}^{j}\alpha_{i,j}v_{i}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ converges to zero while $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\alpha_{i,j}\neq0$ for some $i\in\mathbb{N}$.
One can sees that this property is just property of linear independent set when $I$ is finite. I am curious about have this property been studied or properties related to that. I will be grateful if anyone provide some insights or references about this property.
Edit
I made mistakes when typing the question. What I mean is the FINITE sum of vectors converges to zero while the coefficients does not converge to zero. The above property has been corrected.

What do you mean by the "series" $\sum_{i\in I} \alpha_i v_i$? Do you require absolute summability or unconditional summability (which are different things in infinite dimensions by the Dvoretzky-Rpgers theorem)?

Sorry, I mean to be the finite sum, edited.

What is $n$ then?

should be j then
